# Ajax and Json - Change image after button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have 3 images representing different moods. 
Then I have 2 buttons that sends data with ajax and json and updates values in the database.
I want a different image to show depending on the new value in the database...

**My problem:**
The button I´m testing on works fine with ajax and json but the image does not change unless I refresh the page.

Could someone tell me how to go about this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the image with the one you loaded? Are you sure you shouldn't be using `.replaceWith` ?

Comment: Hi, when user clicks a image button it is updating the database with new values without refreshing the page. And depending on the new value in one of the database fields I want a certain image to load. As for now the correct "mood" image is only showing when I refresh the page...

Comment: Yes, I guess that is my point.  You update the database, but you never update the page that is already loaded. I'll provide an answer below that assumes you are passing back to the ajax function content for the new image that should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're having the change in HTML and fadeIn as the callback rather than occur AFTER the fadeOut upon the AJAX success.

Have you tried `$('#query').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();`?

Answer (score 0):

The section below, it doesn't appear you are overwriting your image, which is why it isn't changing.  Ignore the fadeouts for now to make it simpler

success: function (data) { 
                $('#query').fadeOut(function () {
                    $('#query').html(data).fadeIn();
                });
                console.log('Ajax request returned successfully.');
            },

changes to

```
success: function (data) { 
                $('#ImageElement').replaceWith(data) //This is where you are replacing the html that points to the image 
                                                              //that previously was displayed and now points to the new image contained in the `data` parameter you returned to the function 
                    console.log('Ajax request returned successfully.');
                },
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What should I change #ImageContainerElement to? I don´t have any particular ids on the images..

Comment: @Lisa well you can look at http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/ and just use the `ID` of the image you are replacing and it will swap out he old HTML with the new you pass in `data`.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: But the problem is data parameter is connected to the form element not my "image" elements. This is where I´m lost...

Comment: The images I´m trying to change are located in if statements that echo each one out depending on the value in the database.

Comment: @Lisa Is this the image? I would have specified but I was confused by this section of your code. `<input type="image" class="four columns" src="views/img/tamagotchi/candy.png" />
</form>`

Comment: No that belongs to one of the buttons... The images are further down and in if statements...

Comment: @Lisa Ahhhhhhhh got it.  Well then set a varable that has global scope, set it in your ajax call, and then use it when you echo out to the user. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hm not really:( Echo out the user?

Comment: @Lisa Your line of `echo '<div class="four columns"><img src="views/img/tamagotchi/sick.png" alt="" title="" width="400px"/></div>';` would change to `echo varaibaleISetInMyAjaxFunction;`

Comment: But what about replaceWith? Should I remove that section?

Comment: Also should I make a variable for each image? var happy = happy.jpg, var sad = sad.jpg ... ? Sorry I´m new to this...

Comment: @Lisa No, heh, the whole point is that you are sending back from your controller (where you set in the database) a new image to be displayed to the user. Use one variable and display it to the user once.  You can send back more than one parameter as part of your returned data if you need to accomidate some logic in what you show to your user.

Comment: I don´t get it:(( What should I define the variable to if the images are in the other file? var mood = ? And when I try and echo out I get undefined variable... Also should I remove the hole success: function (data) { ... part?

Comment: @Lisa The name of the variable doesn't matter.  The variable would be the image you want to display. Ex: var example = `<img src="sad.png" /> and then when you echo something to the user, you use the variable instead of the hard coded image.  I think you need a step back.  Your user changes something, you report that change to your server, save that change to the database, when you report that the change was made, you then want to update what you show to the user.  This update back to the client is where you are passing in the information to change what image you are displaying.